# Alternative for switch that only calls methods based on cases values

Tags: c#

Is there a possible way to write the next switch in some shorter, readable code?

```
switch (SomeValue)
{
  case "001": return DoMethod1(); break;
  case "002": return DoMethod2(); break;
  //etc..
}
```

I was thinking in some way like

```
Dictionary<string, Func<int>> MethodsByValue = new Dictionary<string, Func<int>>()
{
    { "001", DoMethod1 },
    { "002", DoMethod2 },
}
```

and call this by doing

```
return MethodsByValue[SomeValue]();
```

But is this even possible? Or am I thinking way to far out of the box. I couldn't find anyting like this but then again, I don't know the keywords for this if it is possible.

EDIT: To answer the request of  Lasse V. Karlsen:

This is how the code is in my project. Changed names at some places cause original names doesn't matter cause it is in my mother language.

```
public string GetRecord420(Dictionary<DataClass, object> dictionaryName)
{
  // some code here
}

public string GetRecord421(Dictionary<DataClass, object> dictionaryName)
{
  // some code here
}

//(Temperary) solution with the switch statement in a wrapper:
public string GetRecordByString(string s, Dictionary<DataClass, object> dictionaryName)
{
  switch (s)
  {
    case "320": return GetRecord420(dictionaryName);
    case "321": return GetRecord421(dictionaryName);
    default: return String.Empty;
  }
}

//How I hoped it could be, with a mapping dictionary.
public Dictionary<string, Func<string, Dictionary<DataClass, object>>> MethodByString = 
   new Dictionary<string, Func<string, Dictionary<DataClass, object>>>()
{
  { "320", GetRecord420 },
  { "321", GetRecord421 },
}
```

DataClass is an Entity class, which stores some column data (column name, column type, etc.).

I tried the dictionary part, but it gives me the error: Cannot convert from method group to System.Func<...>.

Changing to () => GetRecord420 gives me the error: Cannot convert lambda to delegate type System.Func<...> because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: theres no need to write break if you use return before it

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen yes, but I get the error: cannot convert method group to System.Func<...>

Comment: How is `DoMethod1` and `DoMethod2` declared?

Comment: Assuming that it works, do you _really_ find your alternative more readable? I don't.

Comment: Well, maybe it isnt better to read but I think it is helps to prevent when an item needs to be added to the switch statement and I have to search for (let's say for example) 10 switch statements and add the cases to all of them. With a dictionary I only need to that one time, no matter how often the MethodsByValue[SomeValue](); is called. I could also make a wrapper method with parameters that calls the switch one time. and call that method where I need to.

Comment: @Cornelis: The error you're getting is because `DoMethod1` is not defined as a method that returns an int, hence why I asked how the methods are declared.

Comment: The code in the openings post was just a simplyfied example. The actual method is defined this way: `public string MethodName(Dictionary<AClass, object> DictionaryName) { /*the code*/ }`

Comment: Then please post some actual code that demonstrates the actual problem that you have. Solving a different problem is no use to anyone.

Comment: Your second method is advocated [in this post](http://www.simpleprogrammer.com/2010/08/17/pulling-out-the-switch-its-time-for-a-whooping/); I use it myself sometimes.

Comment: @ Lasse V. Karlsen I update the Openings Post with some actual code

Answer (score 1):

There must be an error with your method definitions,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       var methods = new Dictionary<string, Func<int>>
           {
               { "001", DoMethod1 }
           };
    }

    static int DoMethod1()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

is perfectly valid syntax.

but, this is not better than `switch` for 1 compelling and 1 subjective reason.

If you are comparing against constants or literals then you should use switch. This enables the compiler to peform compile time optimizations without additional analysis.

More subjectively, the dictionary/lookup approach is no shorter and I find it harder to read. However, it would be useful in situations where your comparison terms vary at runtime.

If you want avoid rewriting the `switch` factor it into a function. Say,

```
Func<int> MethodsByValue(string value)
{
    switch(value)
    {
        case "001":
            return DoMethod1;

        default:
            return DoMethod2;
    }
}
```

---

**Either way,**

Rather than using some arbritary strings to enumerate your methods, why not use an `enum`? Then you will get additional performance and readability benefits.

Comment: You're assuming that `DoMethod1` isn't actually a method here, aren't you? Judging by the names I would say that's wrong.

Comment: But if it is a method, `() => DoMethod1` won't work as you're not calling the method but attempting to return the method group, which is illegal.

Comment: What I meant by my first comment was that your syntax would only work if `DoMethod1` was not actually a method, but instead a local variable, field, or property. If it's a method, you need the parenthesis.

Comment: It would if you didn't try to wrap it in a lambda expression. His (now edited) syntax does in fact work, adding `() =>` in front of it won't. I asked him if he had tried his own code, let me ask you the same. Did you try it?

Comment: Doing a switch on strings pretty much causes the compiler to generate a dictionary for the lookup. The optimisations you talk about are really only possible with integers.

Comment: @tumtumtum so, the swtich is at least as good the dictionary, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten what you have simply by removing the redundant `break`s, and if it happens that two cases should call the same method then you can fall through:

```
switch (SomeValue) {
  case "001": return DoMethod1();
  case "002": return DoMethod2();
  case "003": 
  case "004": return DoMethod34();
  //etc..
}
```

As for your pseudo suggestion, and the other answer advocating it, I don't see how this is any short or more concise. However, in *usage* is could reduce code and be clear, such as, briefly:

```
Func<int> GetMethod(string key) {
  return MethodsByValue[key];
}
Func<int> method = GetMethod("001");
method();
```

Answer (score 0):

In general a good alternative for switch would be using [State Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state) other good alternative is [Strategy Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy). It will make your code more extensible and is more object oriented approach.

Answer (score 0):

I use a [Mapping extension](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2013/07/21/mapping-map-switch.aspx) for that. This way yoy can use the following syntax:

```
    return SomeValue
    .Map("001", DoMethod1)
    .Map("002", DoMethod2)
     //etc
```

This makes it also possible to do this:

```
    return SomeValue
    .Map(1, DoMethod1)
    .Map(2, DoMethod2)
    .Map(x => x < 0, DoMethod3)
    .Map(x => x > 5  && x < 10, DoMethod4)
    .Else(4); // a simple value of a method
```